# scatter plot with Dash

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, lodash, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I am coding a Dash page to plot some data for myself.
I want to have some dynamic features on some of my plots.

On my dash I have one dropdown, one pie chart and one scatter chart.

Here is my code:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.graph_objs as go

app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Label(['Select the Type:']),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='type_filter',
        options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in df.Type.unique()],
        value='All'
    ),
    dcc.Graph(
        id='allocation_chart'
    ),
    dcc.Graph(
        id='allocation_history_chart'
    ),
])

@app.callback(
    Output('allocation_chart','figure'),
    [
        Input('type_filter', 'value')
    ]
)
def update_allocation(type_):
    if type_ == 'All':
        filtered = df
    else:
        mask = df['Type'] == type_
        filtered = df.loc[mask]
        
    data = [
        go.Pie(
            labels=filtered['Asset'],
            values=filtered['Total']
        )
    ]
    return {
        'data': data,
        'layout': go.Layout(title='Asset Allocation by Type')
    }

@app.callback(
    Output('allocation_history_chart','figure'),
    [
        Input('type_filter','value')
    ]
    
)
def update_allocation_history(type_):    
    if type_ == 'All':
        filtered = df_index
    else:
        mask = df['Type'] == type_
        filtered = df_index.loc[mask]

    data = go.Figure()
    for ticker in filtered.index:
        data.add_trace(
            go.Scatter(
                x = filtered.loc[ticker].index,
                y = filtered.loc[ticker],
                name = ticker
            )
        )
    return {
        'data': [data],
        'layout': go.Layout(title='History of Asset')
    }

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

here is the Dash:
[image]

Here is the scatter chart ran in my Notebook:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVNzv.png]

Everything is working - Dash is running well, i can see the dropdown and the pie chart - except the scatter chart - the second one.
I absolutely don't understand why because when I run the scatter chart in my Notebook it's working pretty well.

If you have any idea, don't hesitate.

Comment: can you include a sample of your `df` in the question so we can more easily reproduce your error? you can copy and paste the output from `df.head().to_dict()` into your question – thanks!

Comment: I think maybe in you `df['Type']` does not have `value = 'All'` so that graph will be blank.